# when to call the Server onClick vs OnClientClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can someone please explain why **btnSaveFile1** is clicked, **onClientClick**() is called and if **onClientClick**() returns true it calls the server but if **onClientClick()** returns false it doesn't call the server. Which I understand fully.

But why isn't that the case for **btnSaveFile2** it seems to never call the server no matter what **onClientClick()**  returns ?

Why does the **return false;** have to be inline ?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveFile1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="if(!onClientClick()){return false;}" OnClick="btnSaveFile_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />


<asp:Button ID="btnSaveFile2" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return onClientClick()" OnClick="btnSaveFile_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />


 <script type="text/javascript">   
       function onClientClick() {
            if (CurrentMemberValidatedWindow()) {
                if (!ValidateForm()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                DeleteInvalidFiles();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: remove `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`

Longer explanation:

> Use the UseSubmitBehavior property to specify whether a Button control
>   uses the client browser's submit mechanism or the ASP.NET postback
>   mechanism. By default the value of this property is true, causing the
>   Button control to use the browser's submit mechanism. **If you specify
>   false, the ASP.NET page framework adds client-side script to the page
>   to post the form to the server.**

If you look at the page source, the `onclick` for the rendered button isn't simply `"if(!onClientClick()){return false;}"` or `"return onClientClick();"`, because it has to add client-side script to post the form. So now for the first button it is:

```
"if(!onClientClick()){return false;};__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$btnSaveFile1','')"
```

and for the second it is

```
"return onClientClick();__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$btnSaveFile2','')"
```

So you can see in case #2, if it returns `true`, it will not reach the script that actually submits the form. (this is not the case for button 1, which does reach the script and thus submits the form).